# Delete duplicate rows not based on primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table in my database:

```
tblAgencies
----------------------
AgencyID (PK)
VendorID
RegionID
Name
Zip
```

Long story short, I accidentally copied my entire table into itself - so every row in my table has a duplicate.

But with my `AgencyID` field being the identity, and automatically incrementing, I need to find duplicates based on all the other fields, since `AgencyID` is unique.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: If your PK is auto incremented, can't you just run a DELETE where the AgencyID > [the last good record]?

Comment: use row_number for whatever columns make a duplicate, and delete where it = 2?

Answer (score 3):

This will keep the oldest AgencyID values, and delete any duplicates otherwise.

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY VendorID, RegionID, Name, Zip
    ORDER BY AgencyID) FROM dbo.tblAgencies
)
DELETE x WHERE rn > 1;
```

Be careful, though; this may not work if other tables reference AgencyID *and* they've obtained any of your newer, erroneous values.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution, use select distinct into a temp table, then reload the original

Comment: This will only work if there's no foreign keys referring to the original table.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you duplicates provided that the combination of all other columns is unique:

```
select * from mytable t1
where exists
         (select * from mytable t2 
         where t1.VendorID = t2.VendorID 
         and t1.RegionID = t2.RegionID 
         and and t1.Name = t2.Name 
         and t1.Zip = t2.Zip 
         and t1.AgencyID > t2.AgencyID)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you all the rows that have duplicate values except for the minimum agencyid row.

```
select *
  from tblAgencies
  where AgencyID not in (select min(AgencyID)
                           from tblAgencies
                           group by VendorID, RegionID, Name, Zip)
```

edit: adding [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/283170/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
;with CTE 
AS
 (
   SELECT ID_Column, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column1, Column2, Column3... ORDER BY ID ASC)
  FROM T
)
DELETE FROM CTE 
WHERE rn >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with CTE 
AS
(SELECT MAX(AgencyID) AgentID,VendorID ,
RegionID ,
Name ,
Zip  FROM tblAgencies
GROUP BY VendorID ,
RegionID ,
Name ,
Zip 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

DELETE FROM tblAgencies WHERE  EXISTS  (SELECT 1 FROM CTE
WHERE  AgentID = tblAgencies.AgencyID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers that will give you what you want here, but there's no need to use a CTE or do any grouping, the simplest way is just:

```
delete   t1
from     tblAgencies t1
join     tblAgencies t2
on       t1.VendorId = t2.VendorId
and      t1.RegionId = t2.RegionId
and      t1.Name = t2.Name
and      t1.Zip = t2.Zip
and      t1.AgencyId > t2.AgencyId
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help: [How to delete duplicates in the presence of a primary key?](http://sql-ex.ru/help/select18.php)